# Pivot table using dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view that contains the following fields...

```
 ConID int
 Task varchar
 MeasureCategory varchar
 State char(2)
 DueDate datetime,
 Frequency char(1)
 Pattern char(1)
 TargetMin decimal
 TargetMax decimal
 Achieved decimal
```

Using variables for the ConID, State, and DueDate, I want to create a pivot table that gives me the Average values for TargetMin, TargetMax, and Achieved, by month, for the month value of the variable for the due date plus each of the preceding four months from that variable. So with an end date variable value of 9/30/2014 I want the values for the DueDate time frames of ...

```
 9/1/2014 - 9/30/2014
 8/1/2014 - 8/31/2014
 7/1/2014 - 7/31/2014
 6/1/2014 - 6/30/2014
```

It also must be for the variable value entered for the ConID and for the State.

All three variables, ConID, State, and DueDate, will change. So for a given ConID in the specified State I want the Average values for TargetMin, TargetMax, and Achieved by month for the past four months ending with the variable value entered for the DueDate.
Within each month there can be multiple entries, or not. Data can be entered as an entry by week or an entry by month. That is why I want the average.

I am new to pivot tables and have no idea on where to begin.

What I need to see is...

```
 -____----------------------------------------- MONTH 1 VALUES___________________ = MONTH 2 VALUES________________ - MONTH 3 VALUES___________________ - MONTH 4 VALUES____________________
 Task - MeasureCategory - Frequency - Pattern - TargetMin - TargetMax - Achieved - TargetMin - TargetMax - Achieved - TargetMin - TargetMax - Achieved - TargetMin - TargetMax - Achieved
```

Comment: Task MeasureCategory Frequency Pattern Month1TargetMin/Max/Achieved Month2TargetMin/Max/Achieved Month3TargetMin/Max/Achieved Month4TargetMin/Max/Achieved

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do the work for you, I want to give you a link on [how to use PIVOT and UNPIVOT in sql-server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (technet.microsoft.com) which has a few examples on basic use. Also, if you search around on the internets you will find plenty of examples about the use of PIVOT on StackOverflow.

If you need the PIVOT to be dynamic, take [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) from StackOverflow.com

Comment: The problem I run into is how to do the date part. I want the date to vary and be based on some end date value. I have not found anything that works with date values in this way.

Comment: @Support I've updated the answer with an example from StackOverflow.com on how to this dynamically.

Comment: @Support Start with a trivialized setup, and work your way to the more complex end-point. If you don't know much about a subject, this is usually the best way to get to your end-point.

Answer (score 0):

Here input is duedate which is a datetime, the `CTE` calculates start and end of the month ending with duedate.
Once we have the month ranges, the `Group By` the due date on each month for the 4 months will give you the average values.

```
declare @duedate datetime = '6/30/2014'
declare @conId int = 100
declare @state char(2) = 'ab'

;with CTE(monthend, monthstart, N)
as
( select DATEADD(MONTH, 0, @duedate) as monthend,  
         DATEADD(MONTH,datediff(MONTH, 0, @duedate),0) as monthstart,  1 
  UNION ALL
  select DATEADD(MONTH,1, monthend) as monthend,
         DATEADD(MONTH,datediff(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(MONTH,1, monthend)),0) as monthstart , N+1
  FROM CTE
  where N <=3
 )
select ConId,
       AVG(TargetMin), 
       AVG(TargetMax),
       AVG(Achieved),
       DATEADD(MONTH,datediff(MONTH, 0, DueDate),0) 
from tableA
JOIN CTE
on  DueDate between cte.monthstart and cte.monthend
and conId = @conId
and State = @State
group by ConId,DATEADD(MONTH,datediff(MONTH, 0, DueDate),0)
```